# How to check transaction before send it

Tags: web3js

Ethereum Wallet will show error message if transaction has error before send. How to do like that using rpc api.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `eth_estimateGas`, or with web3, `estimateGas()`, to simulate what will happen when you run the transaction. This should return an error message if the transaction results in an error.

Be aware that the situation may change between calling `eth_estimateGas` and your actual transaction being mined, so in some cases a transaction that ran without error may still error out when actually sent, or vice versa.

Comment: I try to use eth_estimateGas to send ether to a contract without payable fallback function, but it still return a number without error. How to see whether error happens